# running javascript in a nested component-like django partial template

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, django-views

**I would like to make a "component" (several actually, but let us start with one). That is I would like to have a template file, which itself may include javascript. Then I would like to be able to include that "component" in whatever (other) Django template file.**

Importantly: in the base.html I include utility javascript (like jquery or bootstrap or whatever) and I want those things to be in scope in the component's javascript.

Are there other achitectural ways of achieving this?

Here is a visual of one Django template:
[image: The basic structure]

and when an item is clicked, it will update the other part of the page, allowing that template and its included JS to run with access to the rest of the page's javascript.

[image: With a partial template]

Here is some code to go along with it (I mistyped base to baste, so I went with the theme):

models.py

```
class CommonTask(models.Model):   ## nothing special
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='yummy')
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'food'
urlpatterns = [
    ## the list view on the left
    url(r'^edible/?', views.EdibleList.as_view(), name='edible'),
    ## the partial on the right
    url(r'^billable/edit/(?P<jid>[a-zA-Z0-9-\w:]+)/?', views.EdibleEdit.as_view(), name='edibleEdit'),
```

views.py

```
class EdibleList(ListView):
    template_name = 'food/edible-list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Dish.objects.filter('edible'=True)

class EdibleEdit(UpdateView):
    form_class = EdibleForm
    template_name = 'food/edible-edit.html'

    def get_initial(self):
        …  # for the form/formset info

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Dish, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

baste.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}

<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr" xmlns= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/main.css" %}">
    {% block meta_tags %}{% endblock meta_tags %}
    {% block scripts-head %}{% endblock scripts-head %}
    <title>Edibles -  {% block title%}{% endblock title%}</title>
    {% block extra_head %} {% endblock extra_head %}
  </head>

  <body>
    {% block content %} {% endblock content %}
    {% block scripts %} {% endblock scripts %}
    <script>
      {% block script-inline %} {% endblock script-inline %}
    </script>
    <footer> FOOTER </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

list.html

```
{% extends "baste.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title%}Edible List - {{dish.name}} {% endblock title%}

{% block extra_head %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "food/food.css" %}">
{% endblock extra_head %}

{% block script-inline %}  
    console.log('This works, as it is in the views original compiled template');

    console.log('This does not work, as it relies on the partial to be loaded, but 
       the partial isn't loaded yet, and this wont update after the partial is loaded);
    var interpuncts = document.getElementsByClassName("interpuncts");
    for (let i=0; i < interpuncts.length; i++){
      interpuncts[i].onclick=function(event){
        console.log('gh1');
      };
    };

    // showing the right partial when clicked
    pane = document.getElementById("edible-single");
    showPane = function(link) {
      fetch(link).then(function(response) {
          return response.text();
      }).then(function(body) {
          pane.innerHTML = body;
      });
    };

    let edibleLinks = document.querySelectorAll("a.edible-link");
    edibleLinks.forEach(function(edibleLink) {
        edibleLink.addEventListener('click', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          showPane(edibleLink.getAttribute('href'));
        });
    });

{% endblock script-inline %}  

{% block scripts %} {% endblock scripts %}  

{% block content %}

  {% include "food/nav.html" with currentView="edibleList" %}

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class="text-center">Edible Dishes</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="row scrollable-row">
      <div class="col-3 scrollable-col">    
        <table class="table">
          <tbody>
            {% for dish in dish-list %}
              <tr class="d-flex">
                <td class="col">
                  <a class="edible-link"
                     href="{% url 'food:ediblebleDetail'
                     pk=dish.pk %}" 
                     data-pk="{{dish.pk}}">{{dish.name}}</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col-9 scrollable-col" id="edible-single"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

editPartial.html

```
{% load static %}

{# no blocks work in this, because it can't extend the list.html, because the view #}
{# can't render to endpoint(sibling) templates at the same time #}
{# {% block * %} #}

<script>
  console.log('This won\'t run, as it is loaded separately as just an inclusion
     text from the list AJAX call.')
  $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('This can\'t work because it relies on $ to be accessible, which it is not')
    var interpuncts=document.getElementsByClassName("interpuncts");
    for (let i=0; i < interpuncts.length; i++){
      interpuncts[i].onclick=function(event){
        console.log('I can not get a handle on the partial template items after
          they are loaded as a partial');
      };
    };
  });  
</script>

<div class="container">
  Dish - {{dish.name}}
  <hr>

  <form action="{% form url %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    {# Some element(s) that needs some javascript to act on it, more comprehensive than #}
    {# bootstrap show/hide can do  #}
    <div class="interpuncts">
      ··· Do something with this element
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" value="Save">
  </form>
</div>
```

NOTES:

- This is similar to Rails' partials if I remember, and definitely doable in 'Angular/Ember'.   I think this boils down to some architecture, or package I am unaware of and can't find documentation.  I am unsure of it is doable with inclusion tags.